# Replace fragment from fragment Dagger 2 Kotlin android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

I followed some tutorials and gained somewhat about dagger 2 and implementation. I followed the tutorial and started practicing the code. My query is I need to change the fragment from one fragment. I know the actual method but, I need to know the standard way in dagger 2 for this scenario.
I have two fragments HomeFragment, PracticeFragment
I need to call Practice fragment from HomeFragment
I will paste my code below here

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainContract.View {


    @Inject lateinit var presenter: MainContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        injectDependency()
        presenter.attach(this)
    }

    private fun injectDependency() {
     var activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
         .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
         .build()
        activityComponent.inject(this)
    }

    override fun showHomeFragment() {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.frame,HomeFragment().newInstance(),HomeFragment.TAG)
                .commit()
    }
    override fun showPracticeFragment() {

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.frame,PracticeFragment().newInstance(),PracticeFragment.TAG)
            .commit()

    }

}
```

**MainPresenter**

```
class MainPresenter : MainContract.Presenter {


    private lateinit var view: MainContract.View
    private val subscriptions = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onDrawerOptionsClick() {

    }

    override fun subscribe() {

    }

    override fun unsubscrbe() {
        subscriptions.clear()
    }

    override fun attach(view: MainContract.View) {
        this.view = view
        view.showHomeFragment()
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(),HomeContract.view  {


    @Inject  lateinit var presenter : HomeContract.Presenter

    private lateinit var rootView: View

    fun newInstance(): HomeFragment{
        return HomeFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectDependency()
    }

    private fun injectDependency() {
        val fragmentComponent = DaggerFragmentComponent.builder()
            .fragmentmodule(Fragmentmodule()).build()
        fragmentComponent.inject(this)

    }

    override fun onCreateView (inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated (view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter.attach(this)
         presenter.subscribe()
   }

    override fun showProgress(boolean: Boolean) {
    }

    override fun loadMessageSuccess(message: String) {

    }
    companion object {
        val TAG: String = "HomeFragment"
    }
}
```

**HomePresenter**

```
class HomePresenter : HomeContract.Presenter {
    lateinit var view: HomeContract.view
    override fun loadMessage() {

    }

    override fun subscribe() {

    }

    override fun unsubscrbe() {

    }

    override fun attach(view: HomeContract.view) {
        this.view = view
    }
}
```

And I am also new to the MVP approach. Please, check the above code. Thanks in advance